# Windows Phone 8 keyboard vs Android Keyboard - NEXT/DONE button

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, keyboard

I've been trying to make a "form-like" page in WP8 (based on an android App that is already done by someone else).

The Andoird keyboard has a "NEXT/DONE" button, which would come in handy for filling up the form/skipping between textboxes in it.

Well, I didn't find it in Windows Phone 8, so i decided to use the Keydown event and check for the "Enter" key and use it instead.

But another problem arose, as i filled up inputscopes for the textboxes and found out, that enter is not on every scope's keyboard.

So my question is:

Is there some other possible workaround coming to your mind?

Comment: Although I don't know workaround, but maybe you can put your Next/Done in ApplicationBar. Or maybe this will help you somehow: http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Windows-Phone-7-Creating-Custom-Keyboard.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've posted in comment - you can put your Next/Done buttons in ApplicationBar.
I've also seen [an article about creating own keyboard layout](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Windows-Phone-7-Creating-Custom-Keyboard.aspx), in which you can design additional buttons (but I think AppBar will be simpler).
I think that other ideas - like changing behaviour of buttons in normal keyboard - aren't good, as they can be less intuitive for users and cause some confusion.